# How can be multilevel return achieved in PHP function?

Tags: php, symfony, controller

Let me explain this one.

Assume we have a function - API method named `phone.add` and the end user makes a call to `http://example.com/api/v1/phone.add` with some params. Before executing actual function somewhere in `PhoneManager` class we need to perform 2 universal checks - validate params and access rights.

Let the `phone.add` API method look like this:

```
function phone_add(string $param1, int $param2, callable $param3): float {
   //... validate $param1, $param2, $param3
   //... check access rights

   //... call PhoneManager::add()
   //... return result
}
```

It's obvious that validations can fail and the corresponding response should be formed and sent, but it's a little bit messy to add `if (validation_failed(...)) return new Response(...)` in every API method, so... how is it possible to return from **nested** function the actual **final** response or how this algorithm (set of actions) should be implemented correctly?

Thank u!

Comment: You could actually work with exceptions on this. in the finally method you can build the response (of the try catch block). Alternativ way is to pass the Response as reference to each of the blocks. (Methods or services)

Comment: @ChrisWest, nice idea about exceptions... trying to make it work. Thanks!

Comment: @ChrisWest, post this idea as an answer, please. I've made it with Exceptions - looks fine, but definitely not a 100% perfect solution.

Comment: Another way that I just thought of might be to create an simple object for the message forward and just simple add it to each of the method calls (pass by reference).

Comment: In the end you could add an method to this simple object to process what is has stored and do whatever it is needed to do ;-)